# Updating a given SESSION's info

Tags: php, mysql

**Why is all the input that is submit blank?** (see below). I believe this is due to an error in my JS file.

HTML Form that is getting submitted:

```
                <form method="post" id="FanDetail">
                        <textarea id="bio" name="fan_bio" cols="27" rows="3"></textarea><br />
                        <input id="dob" name="fan_dob" value="(e.g. 01/05/1965)" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                        <div class="ui-widget">
                            <input id="zip" name="term" value="What is your Zipcode?" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                            <input id="actualZip" type="hidden" name="actualzipval" value="" />
                        </div><!--ui-widget :: zip -->
                        <div class="ui-widget">
                            <input id="occup" type="text"  name="term2" value="e.g. Computer Programmer, etc" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                            <input id="actualOccup" type="hidden" name="actualOccupval" value="" />
                        </div><!--ui-widget :: occup -->
                        <input id="fbkurl" type="text"  name="fan_fbk" value="e.g. SportsFan12" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                        <input id="twiturl" type="text"  name="fan_twit" value="e.g. AboutSports2012" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                        <input id="phoNum" type="text"  name="fan_pho" value="cell or home phone" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                <input style="background-image:url('../../img/save.png');" type="submit" name="saveAbout" value="" id="submit" />
                </form>
```

*The JS file that handles the input from the html form:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#FanDetail").submit(function() {
        // store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var bio = $('#bio').val();
        var dob = $('#dob').val();
        var zip = $('#actualZip').val();
        var occup = $('#actualOccup').val();
        var fbkurl = $('#fbkurl').val();
        var twiturl = $('#twiturl').val();
        var phoNum = $('#phoNum').val();
        $.post(
                "../../src/php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php",
                $("form#FanDetail").serialize(),
                function(){
                    $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){
                        $('div.success').fadeIn();
                });
              });
           return false;
        });
    });
```

The PHP file I'm using is getting the `$fan_sess_id()` variable value right, but none of the other inputs are working.

```
try {
    $sth = null; #kill any possible previous connections
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ######## Get  Input to Submit ############## //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $fanBio=$_POST['bio'];
    $fanDob=$_POST['dob'];
    $zipval=$_POST['zip'];
    $occupval=$_POST['occup'];
    $facebookurl=$_POST['fbkurl'];
    $twitterurl=$_POST['twiturl'];
    $phoneNum=$_POST['phoNum'];
    //$fanID=1;
    $fan_sess_id = session_id(); // assign $fan_sess_id to the current sessionID

    ### DB Connection already established above.
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio='$fanBio',fanDob='$fanDob',fanDetLocID='$zipval',occupID='$occupval',
    fanFbk='$facebookurl',fanTwit='$twitterurl',fanPho='$phoneNum'
    WHERE fansessID='$fan_sess_id';
    ");
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Finally, this is the output I get when running `$sth->debugDumpParams();` in my php script above:

```
SQL: [152] 
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio='',fanDob='',fanDetLocID='',occupID='',
    fanFbk='',fanTwit='',fanPho=''
    WHERE fansessID='90707e4c37762a38ffb50883ce64ee1b';
```

Comment: Can you post the html of the form?

Comment: There is the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) that lets you submit forms via Ajax. You might want to look into this. :-)

Comment: Just a curiosity: You set the `name`-attribute for your inputs as well, did you? `<input type="text" name="bio" id="bio" value="foobar" />`. You access the input's value via `$('#bio').val();` which searches for the DOM element with `id="bio"`, but when doing `serialize` the input's `name`-attribute will be used, not the `id`.

Comment: Please see updated code above with HTML all

Comment: @Basti That's what I thought as well and it is exactly what the problem is...

Comment: @Basti ---- HOLY!!!!!!! WOW, I've been trying to get this to work forever and it was an html error! lol I wont be forgetting this one. Thanks so much! + 10000 to you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the input's `name` to the same value you use in your PHP code when accessing `$_POST`.

For example: 
In `<textarea id="bio" name="fan_bio" cols="27" rows="3"></textarea>` change the attribute `name` to `bio` to get it's value as `$_POST["bio"]`.

When you submit a HTML form, the form element's `name`-attribute is used to reference the value, not the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong array keys to `$_POST`. Instead of the HTML form element id attributes, you need to be using the `name` attributes.

```
$fanBio=$_POST['fan_bio'];
$fanDob=$_POST['fan_dob'];
$zipval=$_POST['term'];
$occupval=$_POST['occup'];
$facebookurl=$_POST['fan_fbk'];
$twitterurl=$_POST['fan_twit'];
$phoneNum=$_POST['fan_pho'];
```

You have another very significant problem.  Though you are using PDO, you have not used placeholders in your prepared statement, leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.   Instead of passing variables directly into the SQL, replace them with placeholders.

```
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio=:fanBio,fanDob=:fanDob,fanDetLocID=:zipval,occupID=:occupval,
    fanFbk=:facebookurl,fanTwit=:twitterurl,fanPho=:phoneNum
    WHERE fansessID=:fan_sess_id;
    ");
    $arr_params = array(
     ':fanBio'=>$fanBio, 
     ':fanDob'=>$fanDob,
     ':zipval'=>$zipval,
     ':occupval'=>$occupval,
     ':facebookurl'=>$facebookurl,
     ':twitterurl'=>$twitterurl,
     ':phoneNum'=>$phoneNum,
     ':fan_sess_id'=>$fan_sess_id
    );
    // Execute the statement with the parameters array
    $sth->execute($arr_params);
```